# Как в Visual Studio посмотреть не пользовательский код?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net

Как в Visual Studio for Web 2013 посмотреть не пользовательский код (то есть код из подключенных пространств имен)?
Хочу установить там брекпойнт. Нашел в Object Browser лишь перечисление классов, но не сам код.

Answer (score 4):

Брекпойнт можно поставить и без просмотра кода - не обязательно открывать код и нажимать на конкретной строчке F9. Можно поставить брекпойнт по имени функции.

Достаточно включить отладку чужого кода: снять чекбокс Debug/Options/Enable Just My Code.

Потом просто поставить брекпойнт:

- открыть Debug/New Breakpoint/Break at Function
- ввести имя класса и метода. Или просто имя метода Например брекпойт на "Update" поставит брекпойнты на все методы Update во всех классах во всех подключенных сборках.
- если будет показано окно с предупреждением - прочитать и проигнорировать
- проверить результат в окне Breakpoints

Если повезет, и если для стороннего кода есть проиндексированные отладочные символы - вам покажет исходный код. Если не повезет - то покажет только call stack, locals и переданные параметры - т.е. все кроме самих исходников.

Если вам нужна именна пошаговая отладка исходников:

Для сборок фреймворка ее можно настроить автоматически - поставить Enable .NET framework source stepping в Debug/Options.

Для другого кода, исходников которого у вас нет - можно воспользоваться бесплатным [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/help/Generating_PDB_Files.html) или платными  [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Generating_PDB_Files.html) / [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) - они умеют декомпилировать и генерировать индексированные отладочные символы для сторонних сборок.

Answer (score 4):

Вы не можете поставить точку останова в коде, для которого у вас нету исходников и/или pdb-файлов (так называемые «символы»).

Если вы хотите отладить код сторонней библиотеки, <s>это скорее всего не получится</s> можно воспользоваться встроенной в Visual Studio 2019 [поддержку декомпиляции](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/decompilation?view=vs-2019). Она работает, начиная с версии 16.5. Для некоторых более ранних версий Студии поддержка [можно тоже включить](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/go-to-and-peek-definition?view=vs-2019#view-decompiled-source-definitions-instead-of-metadata-c), но результат не гарантирован. «Под капотом» у этой декомпиляции находится проект [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy), которым можно пользоваться и отдельно.

Кроме того, вы можете воспользоваться коммерческими декомпиляторами наподобие .NET Reflector'а. Подробности, как ни странно, на [официальном сайте](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/). Учтите, что он небесплатный, хотя и недорогой.

Если же вы, однако, хотите протрассировать библиотеки .NET framework, Microsoft специально предоставила Reference Source и .pdb на своём сервере. Вам лишь надо правильно настроить Visual Studio [[1]](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-dotnet-framework-source), [[2]](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/setup.html):

1. Tools → Options → Debugging → General:

   - отключите *Just My Code*
   - включите *Enable .NET Framework source stepping*
   - включите *Enable source server support*
   - отключите *Require source files to match exactly the original version* (т. к. source server автоматически добавляет блок с копирайтом)
   - отключите *Step over properties and operators*
2. Tools → Options → Debugging → Symbols:

   - укажите место для загруженных .pdb (вам понадобится много места, возможно, лучше не класть их на системный диск)
   - убедитесь, что Microsoft Symbol Servers не подключены (!) (информация там не содержит ссылок на исходный код)
   - если у вас уже есть загруженные (старые) .pdb, возможно, вам придётся удалить их.

Comment: > Вы не можете поставить точку останова в коде, для которого у вас нету исходников и/или pdb-файлов (так называемые «символы»). - в .net брекпойнт можно поставить без символов.

Comment: @PashaPash: Внутри функции тоже?

Comment: да, если знаете смещение. `System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(System.EventArgs) + 0x0000000b`, например. Ну или поставить брекпонйт на начало и потом уже в disassembly ткнуть на конкретную строку. Так что вопрос скорее в удобстве. Если нужно просто посмотреть значения параметров, проверить, вызывается ли вообще функция, или поставить брекпонйт на выход из функции - символы не нужны.

Comment: @PashaPash: То есть какой workflow вы предлагаете? (1) просмотреть исходник функции, (2) узнать у внутреннего Нострадамуса смещение второго `while` в нём, (3) забить это в свойства точки останова. Так?

Comment: Не выворачивайте наизнанку. Я предлагаю в конкретных случаях - проверить сам факт вызова, или посмотреть параметры, или узнать откуда именно вызывается просто брать и ставить брекпойнт по имени, в две кнопки. А вы в этом случае предлагаете (1) выкачать платную тулзу (2) сгенерить ей отладочные символы с дизассемблером, (3) открыть исходники, найти строчку и нажать там F9. Потому что "вы не можете поставить точку останова в коде, для которого у вас нету исходников и/или pdb-файлов ".

Comment: @PashaPash: То, что вы предлагаете, не есть production-решение. Вы предлагаете то, что работает в некоторых случаях, да и то если не хотеть слишком многого. Если вы занимаетесь коммерческим программированием и продали хотя бы два-три экземпляра программы, стоимость плагина уже отбилась.

Comment: Vlad, я не предлагаю так делать. Я просто указываю на то, что в общем случае для постановки брекпойнта pdb и исходники не нужны. А у вас написано "нет, нельзя!" То, что я предлагаю делать - написано в моем ответе. Вы же читали его, перед тем, как писать свой? И да, там есть ссылка на бесплатную утилиту для генерации индексированных pdb,

Comment: Незнание способах постановки брекпойнта - это не "production-решение", это неумение пользоваться доступными инструментами. Ну ок, раз вы считаете что нельзя ставить брекпойнты без символов - значит нельзя. Постараюсь больше так не делать. :)

Comment: @PashaPash: нет, я не читал ваш ответ, когда писал свой. Если возможно декомпилировать и расставить номера строк другими утилитами — это тоже хорошо. Но это же умеет и рефлектор. Утилиты надо выбирать не по критерию «какая дешевле», а по критерию «какая лучше». Иначе ваши программисты будут вместо продуктивной работы сражаться с низкоуровневыми вещами наподобие смещения в IL-коде.

Comment: dotPeek - это утилита от jetbrains, она же встроена в решарпер.  Решарпер - уж точно не самый худший инструмент. Бесплатность dotPeek - это попытка отъесть часть рынка после того, как рефлектор стал платным. А вовсе не показатель плохого качества.

Comment: @PashaPash: Я не утверждаю, что dotPeek плохой, и если моя реплика была так понята, то я неправильно выразился. Просто вы сказали, что у вас есть ссылка на _бесплатную_ утилиту, а я хотел сказать, что бесплатность не важна. Я понял вас так, будто вы противопоставляете _платную_ утилиту _бесплатной_. Поэтому если вы хвалите утилиту, лучше скажите, что она _качественнее_, _удобнее_, _продуктивнее_, а не _дешевле_.

Comment: Ок, она качественее, удобнее, продуктивнее, и дешевле. и еще ее можно легально скачать в моей стране. А reflector скачать нельзя.

Comment: @PashaPash: Ну, давайте я повторюсь. Если вы разрабатываете коммерческий продукт, то рефлектор можно купить, он _крайне дешёвый_. Так что «нельзя скачать» не означает практически ничего.