# Как реализуется разделение объявления и реализации методов без использования partial?

Tags: c#

В метаданных C# постоянно встречается подобный код:

```
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;
using System.Security;

namespace System
{
    public class Object
    {
        public Object ( );
        ~Object ( );
        public static bool Equals ( Object objA, Object objB );
        public static bool ReferenceEquals ( Object objA, Object objB );
        public virtual bool Equals ( Object obj );
        protected Object MemberwiseClone ( );
    }
}
```

Конечно, я убрал комментарии и атрибуты. Здесь нигде нет слова partial, как же тогда реализуется разделение объявления и реализации(тела метода)?
Попробовал сделать подобное у себя, компилятор ругается.

```
public struct U:IComparable
{
    public static int Parse();
    public int CompareTo ( object value );
}

public struct U
{
    public static int Parse()
    {
        return default;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object value)
    {


        return default;
    }
}
```

И это понятно, но этот код - часть кода UInt32.
Так или иначе, мне нужен исходный код, например, как реализуется String.(Там массив символов, или что?) Возможно ли это узнать прямо в Visual Studio, или обязательно смотреть где-то на стороне?

Comment: Так это просто метаданные. Код на самом деле внутри методов, а не отдельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В C#, в отличие от C++, нету разделения на объявление и реализацию. Существует исключение, при котором код реализации метода импортируется из другого места (`extern`), но оно встречается довольно редко.

То, что вы видите — это просто отображение для вас метаданных, которое *не являются реальным кодом на C#*. В реальности, кстати, класс `System.Object` [выглядит вот так](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs) (убрал атрибуты и комментарии, сократил код):

```
public class Object
{
    public Object() { }                
    public virtual String ToString() => GetType().ToString();
    public virtual bool Equals(Object obj) => RuntimeHelpers.Equals(this, obj);
    public static bool Equals(Object objA, Object objB) 
    {
        if (objA == objB) return true;
        if (objA == null || objB == null) return false;
        return objA.Equals(objB);
    }
    public static bool ReferenceEquals (Object objA, Object objB) => objA == objB;        
    public virtual int GetHashCode() => RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(this);
    public extern Type GetType();
    ~Object() { }
    protected extern Object MemberwiseClone();
    private void FieldSetter(String typeName, String fieldName, Object val)
    {
        Contract.Requires(typeName != null);
        Contract.Requires(fieldName != null);

        FieldInfo fldInfo = GetFieldInfo(typeName, fieldName);

        if (fldInfo.IsInitOnly)
            throw new FieldAccessException(
                Environment.GetResourceString("FieldAccess_InitOnly"));     
        System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Message.CoerceArg(val, fldInfo.FieldType);    
        fldInfo.SetValue(this, val);
    }
    private void FieldGetter(String typeName, String fieldName, ref Object val)
    {
        Contract.Requires(typeName != null);
        Contract.Requires(fieldName != null);

        // Extract the field info object
        FieldInfo fldInfo = GetFieldInfo(typeName, fieldName);

        // Get the value
        val = fldInfo.GetValue(this);            
    }
    private FieldInfo GetFieldInfo(String typeName, String fieldName)
    {
        Contract.Requires(typeName != null);
        Contract.Requires(fieldName != null);
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<FieldInfo>() != null);

        Type t = GetType();
        while (null != t)
        {
            if(t.FullName.Equals(typeName))
                break;
            t = t.BaseType;
        }

        if (null == t)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        FieldInfo fldInfo = t.GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.Public | 
                                                  BindingFlags.Instance | 
                                                  BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
        if(null == fldInfo)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        return fldInfo;
    }
}
```

Вы видите, что у всех не-`extern`-методов есть тело. И что в отображении метаданных нету приватных функций.

---

Ключевое слово `partial` не позволяет разделять объявление и имплементацию функций. Оно всего лишь позволяет различные методы одного класса реализовывать в разных файлах исходного кода.

Comment: Вот, хорошо, откуда вы взяли этот код? Я могу его увидеть через Visual Studio?

Comment: @VictorGorban: У меня ж в ответе ссылка есть.

Comment: Да, спасибо, теперь я знаю, где искать исходный код, я могу то же самое прочитать через Visual Studio, или это невозможно, т.к. исходные файлы уже переведены из текста в какой-нибудь бинарник?

Comment: @VictorGorban: В Visual Studio исходников .NET нету, есть только бинарники. Но можно подключить: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/429880/10105. При этом вы даже отлаживать сможете (не так удобно, как свои исходники, конечно).

Comment: Большое спасибо, исчерпывающий ответ.

Comment: @VictorGorban: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!